# array not working for dynamic form field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays, forms

I've found most of the pieces i've needed for this form (making the fields dynamic, etc.) however now the array part of this doesn't seem to work to be able to submit correctly.

what i'm trying to accomplish:
a form with a select field that can be duplicated dynamically and then be submitted as a part of the form to it's own table. so if we add and choose three people in the one form, it submits to it's own attending table with a foreign key back to the event the form is for. had to make it dynamic because we'll never know for sure how many people will be attending said event, but it has to happen all in one form. just because it does. my boss says so.

here's my javascript for the add another field button:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

            // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            // manipulate the id value of the input inside the new element
            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'attendee' + newNum).attr('name', 'attendee[' + newNum + ']');

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

            // enable the "remove" button
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            // business rule: you can only add 5 names
            if (newNum == 6)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
```

here's what the field starts out as in the form:

```
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
    <select name="attendee[1]" id="attendee1" style='float:right;margin-right:4.5%;'>
    <option value=''>Please choose one...</option>
    <?php
    while($row_attendees = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_attendees)){
        $attendee_id = $row_attendees['attendee_id'];
        $attendee_name = $row_attendees['name'];

        echo "<option value='".$attendee_id."'>".$attendee_name."     </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select><label style='width:100px;display:inline-block;line-height:28px;' for="attendee">Attendee</label>
    </div>
```

I'm getting all the things to change correctly. all of the select inputs are being id'd and name'd correctly. the div is being updated the same. all of that works correctly. what doesn't is when i go to submit. here's my php:

```
    foreach($_POST['attendee'] as $attendee){
    $sql_attendees = "INSERT into marketing_calendar.attending (event_title, attendee_id) VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."','".$attendee."')";  
    $res_attendees = mysql_query($sql_attendees) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

all the tutorials i used to pull this together show this as correct. however it doesn't work. i'm only getting whatever the first dropdown is, and nothing else is populating into the array. at least that's all it shows/submits if i run the form or echo the attendee variable in the foreach statement. PLEASE HELP! :)

thanks a ton in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have tried a few ways discussed with another user to display the array for $_POST['attendee'], however it still just shows 1 id in the array, and not however many fields i've actually added. I've also tried removing the number from the array in the select's name attribute. so it would just be name='attendee[]' instead of name='attendee[1]' and so on. this also doesn't help any. can someone please help with why my dynamically added fields aren't being added to the array?

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($_POST['attendee']);` on your php page?

Comment: does it matter where I put this? does it need to be in the foreach loop or just in the if submit somewhere

Comment: Try to print the array and if it fetches all the option, then you need to hceck your js part if you are loading the dropdown via AJAX

Comment: can you post your html output? it appears like all the selects are being named attendee[1] ?

Comment: all of the selects are being named correctly. attendee[1], attendee[2], etc. when i printed the array i get: Array ( [1] => 1 ). so it's still only catching one select on there even though i had three.

Comment: @sixeightzero -- do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into a JSfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/rv8Mv/1/

It looks like the selects are being added correctly.  You can check by clicking the "Submit" button, which shows a data string of what will be submitted to the server.

One thing you might want to check, is to make sure you are enclosing all the select elements inside a `<form>` element, which you didn't include in your question.

I think your problem is in the PHP code on the server.

On the server, make sure you are receiving all the variables by using this code:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        error_log($key.' -> '.$value;
    }
?>
```

Then check your error log to see the names and values for all the POST variables.

You are probably not referencing the POST variables correctly in your current PHP code.

Comment: if i'm doing this for each for just the attendee part, what would $key and $value be? i've got about zero experience with arrays. obviously.

Comment: Try the code I put there and check the error log, everything will be clear.  It should show you all the `$_POST` variables in the error log.

Comment: The `$key` will show "name" from your form, and the `$value` will should the value from the form.

Comment: If i do the code exactly how you put it, i get 1 -> array. If i do the same loop with foreach($_POST['attendee'] etc etc I get 1 -> 9. which is the first of the three selects I did and it ignores the other two still. the others are not being added to the array.

Comment: OK, are you sure your MySQL query is executing correctly?  You have `die(mysql_error())` which will stop the for loop.

Comment: it's putting up exactly what the array is showing. if i can't get the array to have more than one number in it, then the query isn't going to put up more. there has to be an error before that. have three selects that have name='attendee[1]', name='attendee[2]', name='attendee[3]', shouldn't there be three numbers in that array we're trying to show?

Comment: yes the `foreach` loop should run for each element of the array, and the error_log should ouput 3 lines: 1 -> X, 2 -> X, and 3 -> X.

Comment: when I use this:
`code`foreach($_POST['attendee'] as $key => $value){
        error_log($key.' -> '.$value,1,"example@example.com","From: webmaster@example.com");
    }

it just sends me 1->1. whatever the first select was. never the others after it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your sql to look like this:

```
foreach($_POST['attendee'] as $attendee){
    $sql_attendees = "INSERT into marketing_calendar.attending (event_title, attendee_id) VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."',".$attendee.")";  
    $res_attendees = mysql_query($sql_attendees) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Your `attendee_id` is an int column. You were wrapping the column content with single quotes, which denotes a string. This would result in your `attendee_id` being null if your column is defined as nullable.

Comment: Mysql can usually handle integers inside quotes so that should not be problem.